# How display specific category post to specific users?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, customization

All

In my application, I am really confused that how to set the project flow in wordpress.

There are 3 Users.
1. Admin : High level mgmt
2. Doctors :  Add patients reports
3. Patients : Can see reports added by doctors.

I am considering post as a reports.

Prob 1: How to assign specif (user)doctor to  patient(user)? While patient(user) fill the registration form.

Prob 2: After patient select doctor while filling the form, now doctor can generate reports to specific users(patients).

Prob 3: How display specific category post(Patients Reports) to specific 
users(Patients)?

I Know there is no ready made plugin for it, i just want to know that how to set this flow in wordpress and which plugins can help me.
What should i need to customize ?

Thanks In advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a stab. I won't include any code examples, just the path I would take.

**Users**

I image when you say "users" you mean different roles for users. "doctor user" is just a user with the role of "doctor" (see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

So, I would start by creating 2 new roles: "doctor" and "patient".

**Problem 1**

The simplest way to create a relation between 2 users (a doctor and a patient) would be to use `usermeta`. I would store the patient's doctor `user_id` in the patient's `usermeta`. You will have to do some custom registration form to show a list of doctors (`get_users( 'role=doctor' )`) then save the usermeta for the new user on `wp_insert_user`.

**Problem 2**

I don't know what your reports are, but if a doctor just needs to be able to get a list of their patients, you would need to do a `$wpdb->get_col()` on the `usermeta` table (as you stored it in the patient's usermeta, you can't use the get_usermeta API.

**Problem 3**

Presumable you will use a custom post type for reports, and you want the patient to only be able to see their own report. To do this I would probably save some `postmeta` on the patient report of `_patient_user_id`. Then when you want to show the reports for a user you can do something like

```
new WP_Query( 'post_type=report&meta_key=_patient_user_id&meta_value=' . get_current_user_id() )
```

(or something similar).

Personally, I probably wouldn't use any plugins here - you could use a role manager plugin for the roles, but creating them programmatically is pretty quick. Again, you can get plugins to create your custom post types - IMO it's a lot easy and better to do it all with code.

Comment: You know bro,i got the perfect as i want . Thanks :)